# Phonegap 2.9 android toast plugin

Tags: android, cordova

What is best toast plugin in phonegap 2.9?

I used [this](https://github.com/giver/cordova-android-toast-plugin) plugin, but NOT working.

CatLog say : `exec() call to unknown plugin : ToastPlugin`

Please Help me.. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are links ([first](https://github.com/giver/cordova-android-toast-plugin), [second](http://teusink.blogspot.in/2013/04/phonegap-android-toast-plugin.html)) for android toast message plugin, please try if it works for you.

There are some changes that you would like to do:

1. In res-> xml-> config.xml write this line

   `<plugin name="ToastPlugin" value="org.apache.cordova.plugin.ToastPlugin"/>`
2. Set `<script src="toast.js"></script>` in your html page properly.

Comment: I used this plugin, but catlog say that..
CatLog say : exec() call to unknown plugin : ToastPlugin

Comment: hey @Dong Ju Jung  what is your main package name ?

Comment: You mean, Main Activity package? that is 'com.test.nfc', And that plugin's .java file copy to org.apache.cordova.api package

Comment: do you have paste ToastPlugin.java on com.test.nfc package

Comment: no not you just paste   ToastPlugin.java  file on your main package. and change the plugin value like 'com.test.nfc.ToastPlugin.java'

Comment: Yeap, you mean paste? Ok, I'll try! Thanks

Comment: Not working.. Toast need some permission? In html, can not found toast plugin

Comment: Working very well! Thanks @Amit Prajapati! You save my life...:)

Comment: what you have try second one or first

Comment: Second one. that very well

Answer (score 0):

If you're on PhoneGap 3: check out this one, which supports iOS as well: http://www.x-services.nl/phonegap-toast-plugin/796